# How to get the Class in constructor with typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, reflection, prototype, instantiation

I try to set, to empty string, every properties of my classes at instantiate time. But to get ALL the properties, I need to get the "Class" who is instantiate in the constructor. Any help would be much appreciate !

I work with typescript 3.1

- Any ideas how can I get the Class in the constructor ?
- Or how can I get a list of all the properties, including the none instantiates ones, only in using "this" and not the Class?

Here the function I'm using to get all properties of a Class.

```
      Export class Base {
        id: String;
        ...

         constructor() {
           getAllProperties(MyClass) 
             // I would like to have MyClass to be dynamique
         }

      }

       function getAllProps(cls: new (...args: any[]) => any): any[] {   
         // return a list of all Class properties.
       }
```

I also tried to use Reflect.metadata API but could not got any good results without the Class.

Answer (score 0):

The parent constructor is called before the children constructor, therefore it won't work. You can create the function and call it after the super() function

```
// Parent
class A1 {
    constructor() {
    }

    protected init() {
        //Get properties here
        console.log(this);
    }
}

// Child
class A2 extends A1 {
    public a;
    public b;

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.a = 1;
        this.b = 2;
        //code here...

        this.init();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't want to instantiate the properties like so this.a = "foo". I'm working on a big project and I would like to do that in the parent Class. In your exemple it would be easier to initiate all the properties in every child class.

Comment: So maybe you can either call the this.init() function anytime you want to see the current state of the child class or setTimeout with the 0 delays to the parent constructor.

Comment: I could not get the properties without having the Class. "this" doesn't give me the proprieties who are not instantiate, they are not Enumerable, so this.foo = undefined.